# Como quitar los domingos en un rango de fechas en c#

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-8.0

Quisiera saber como puedo quitar los domingos entre dos fechas:

```
DateTime fechaUno = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-12-24 13:30:15");
DateTime fechados = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-06-15 09:30:00");
```

Es decir que entre esas dos fechas me cuente los días que hay excepto los domingos.

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste. Revisar [ask], saludos

Comment: Hola @EminUrbina, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles y marcar como aceptadada la que mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
int totalDias = 0;

for (DateTime dia = fechaUno; dia <= fechaDos; dia = dia.AddDays(1))
{
    if (dia.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        totalDias++;
    }
}

//Imprimir el total de días
```

Se hace un **ciclo for** desde **fechaUno** hasta **fechaDos**, se pregunta si el día no es **Domingo**, de no serlo se incrementa en **1** la **variable totalDias**. Finalmente se imprime el valor guardado en la **variable totalDias**.

Answer (score 1):

Envio otra alternativa con LINQ, que te puede servir de ayuda o guía. Utilizando el método [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=net-7.0) obtiendo el rango de dias, para luego ir sumando al inicio cada dia (para obtener el rango de fechas), pero en el where de la query LINQ, filtrar los dias que son domingo.

Lo dejo mas bien como "alternativa" a la solucion de iteración.

Puedes ver [el ejemplo online aquí: "linq-datetime-range-without-sunday"](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZGPwLc) o [en Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/29fbb6468ca0923e4a6f508ec6b4d169)

El codigo:

```
    var inicio = new DateTime(2022, 12, 18);
    var fin = new DateTime(2023, 5, 1);

    
    var dias = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + fin.Subtract(inicio).Days)
                         .Select(offset => inicio.AddDays(offset))
                         .ToArray(); 
    
    var diasSinDomingo = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + fin.Subtract(inicio).Days)                                    
                                   .Where(offset => (inicio.AddDays(offset)).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                                   .Select(offset => inicio.AddDays(offset))
                                   .ToArray(); 
    
    Console.WriteLine($" Dias en el rango: {dias.Count()}"); //dias en el rango: 135
    Console.WriteLine($" Dias en el rango (sin domingos): {diasSinDomingo.Count()}"); //dias en el rango: 115
```

Comment: Tu solución si bien es correcta me parece bastante rebuscada y complicada para solucionar algo tan simple de resolver, me parece que te estás complicando demasiado, aunque no dejo de reconocer que es una solución curiosa y diferente y original

Comment: Es una "alternativa", por eso lo aclare. Si bien en ambas internanamente hay un recorrido cuando se compila en IL. Voy a ver si puedo generar un benchamark entre las dos.

Comment: La eficiencia es importante, pero también la legibilidad, limpieza y mantenimiento del código, un código eficiente en cuanto a velocidad de ejecución pero inteligible y difícil de mantener, por muy rápido que se ejecute no es eficiente ya que sus costos de mantenimiento aumentan

Answer (score 0):

Falta conocer si entre los requisitos de tu programa deben contarse el primer y último días (inclusive) o no, ten presente que este factor puede verse afectado por el componente horario de los tipos DateTime. En todo caso, un ejemplo de código básico para hacer el cálculo puede ser este:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime fechaUno = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-12-24 13:30:15");
        DateTime fechaDos = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-06-15 09:30:00");

        int count = 0;
        for (DateTime date = fechaUno; date <= fechaDos; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Days between the two dates (excluding Sundays): {0}", count);
    }
}
```

Dependiendo de la funcionalidad que necesite tu programa, puedes evitar la distorsión en el cálculo de días que puede producir el componente horario de DateTime utilizando la [propiedad Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-7.0):

```
DateTime fechaUno = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-05-01 13:30:15").Date;
DateTime fechaDos = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-05-15 09:30:00").Date;
```

Comment: GRACIAS A TODOS POR SUS COMENTARIOS ME FUERON DE MUCHA AYUDA